Is it true a cloud of free electrons emits no radiation?
We all know that atomic matter emits blackbody radiation according to its temperature even if no electrons are excited within that matter, however as far as I know no mechanism exists for blackbody radiation to be emitted by a cloud of free electrons unless ions, photons or magnetic fields are present.  Is this true?

No. A free electron cloud can have a temperature, just like any other "stuff". Even a free electromagnetic field can have a temperature (and the two would be strongly coupled).

@FlatterMann The OP's question may be: if the electron cloud have a temperature, and all things with temperature above absolute zero must radiate energy in the form of EM waves, then 1) is the electron cloud actually radiating energy? and if yes, 2) what is the mechanism for this radiation emission?

The OP made the statement that a free electron cloud can not radiate. That is false, hence my "no". A free electron cloud can radiate electromagnetic waves without the need for positive charges. The mechanism with and without positive charges is exactly the same. The total charge may or may not be zero, but that makes no difference for the energy transfer between the could and the em field.

@FlatterMann thank you. As you seem familiar with thermodynamic thinking, suppose there is a chess board in empty space. The number of microstates depends on the number of pieces on the board, so one can say $\frac{dS}{dm}$ where $m$ is the number of pieces on the board, right? This can be related to temperature such that for instance $T \propto \frac{1}{m}$. As we are thinking in rather abstract, dual-representation type of reasoning, how appropriate is it to use various thermodynamics machinery, e.g. Stefan Boltzmann's law $\frac{P}{A} \propto T^4$, to conclude that T must be dissipating...

... over time, so therefore the chess board must be evaporating over time? Is there any physical reality to the notion of a chess board evaporating, or perhaps one is taking duality too far in this case?

@James I don't see what a chessboard has to do with thermodynamics. kT is an energy. Nothing on a chess board has energy. People need to stop comparing physics with combinatorics. They are not the same.

@FlatterMann I am not sure either... I was following the microstates definition of entropy. A different example would be: Suppose my bookshelf has 100 books, Then it has entropy due to the number of microstates configuration, correct? But this definition of $S$ can always be linked afterwards to temperature $T$. So now my bookshelf also has a temperature, purely due to the number of possible microstates configuration of the books on the shelf?

How do you prevent magnetic fields being present in a cloud of moving charges?

'even if no electrons are excited within that matter' This implies absolute zero temperature, hence no black body radiation.

@James As soon as you throw a temperature in you have to talk about a dynamic system with motion. A chessboard doesn't move.

If you have a bunch of charges in a bag at arbitrary positions then the bag will have an electric dipole moment, a magnetic dipole moment, a quadrupole moment etc. If you now give the charges some velocity distribution, then you will get non-zero second time derivatives of these quantities and hence electromagnetic radiation.
Take the simplest example - two electrons separated by $r$. Clearly there will be an acceleration $\ddot{r}>0$, an accelerating electric dipole moment, and consequent electromagnetic radiation.
This could be termed "electron-electron bremsstrahlung". It is usually ignored in neutral plasmas because it is less efficient than the usual electron-ion bremsstrahlung until the electron energies approach the rest-mass energy of the electron. It becomes twice as efficient as electron-ion bremsstrahlung at ultra high energies.
The emissivity due to this process depends on the square of the electron density and has been calculated in detail by Haug 1989 for thermal plasmas in an astrophysical context.
Whether the net emission from the cloud could approach blackbody radiation would depend on how large and how dense the cloud was. It needs to be optically thick enough that the mean free path of a photon of any wavelength is smaller than the cloud. The absorption processes are the microscopic inverse of the emission processes - i.e. inverse bremsstrahlung; but Thomson and Compton scattering will play a role.

Blackbody radiation is a thermal emission of idealized properties, with spectrum the same as radiation in thermodynamic equilibrium has. No real body or system radiates exactly that, although they can get close, like Sun or CMB.
What you mean is thermal radiation/thermal emission. For a given temperature, this can be, at any frequency, less or equally strong to what blackbody radiation would be (if net emission is stronger than that of a blackbody, the surplus radiation is classified as not due to thermal emission, e.g. fluorescence). The fact the system produces thermal emission does not imply the system has to be made of atoms at all, hot  plasma has a thermal emission (Sun's photosphere, discharge lamp, etc.). The denser the plasma is, the closer the emission spectrum gets to that of a blackbody radiation.
A free electron cloud isn't easy to find , because electrons are attracted to positive ions, and most candidates are likely to turn out to be neutral plasma (which can have thermal emission).   But we can find microscopic electron clouds with millions-billions  of electrons in so-called bunches in electron beams in circular accelerators - cyclotrons, synchrotrons. If it was dense enough, and hot enough, it would have noticeable thermal emission (which too would not be exactly blackbody radiation). But electron bunches usually have much stronger synchrotron radiation, due to their fast accelerated motion, so their thermal emission would be weak and very hard to detect.

A cloud of electrons will explode, probably in a fireball. So yes, there will be black body radiation.
Plasma's are good black body radiators, as they have a wide continuous range of excitations. The Sun is a good example. A cloud of electrons would be a plasma, although not a neutral one.
